# set order of collection for custom module in ASC order

Tags: mysql, magento

I have created a custom module. and when call collection of module. i want to set order according to column but its giving me reverse result.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('inventory/inventory')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('product_sku',trim($sku))->setOrder('qty','ASC');
```

it gives me value with large qty first then smaller and smaller.I want small qty first then bigger and bigger

Comment: Have you tried `DESC` instead of `ASC`?

Comment: solved it was datatype problem. my field was of varchar type and i changed it to bigint